# How to dynamically render images using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native

I am currently struggling with rendering some images on my React Native application. Currently, my app is connected to a database, which contains the image file names (ex: 'swipe1') that I want to render in my FlatList. However, it is my understanding that React Native has an issue with this due to its dynamic nature. All of the images I want to use are already saved in a local folder within the app, so I just want the app to be able to pull the picture name from the database and render it. Help!

```
const CardList = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/', {
            method:'GET'
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(listing => {
            setData(listing)
        })

    }, [])

    const compileImagePath = (imageName) => {
        return `../../assets/images/${imageName}.png`;
    };
    
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
                const imagePath = compileImagePath(item.image);
                console.log(imagePath)
                return (
                    <Image source={require(imagePath)} style={styles.image} />
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your RN project is configured to bundle the assets in with your JS bundle.  This is something that is [pretty easy to do with Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/assets/).  I'm not sure what the configuration steps would be for a bare RN project.

Answer (score 0):

Static assets like images, fonts,... need to be declared to be embedded in the app at compile-time. App can **NOT** dynamically load static assets at run-time.

Possible solution :

**1. Host images on your servers or use public cloud providers, S3 , Cloudinary....**

**2. Declare required static images  to compile-time**

Inside top-level file (`App.js`)

```js
// Declare  static assets to be loaded and embedded  at compile-time
export const StaticAssets = {
  "image-1": "../../assets/images/image-1.png",
  "image-2": "../../assets/images/image-2.png",
  "image-3": "../../assets/images/image-3.png",
  "image-n": "../../assets/images/image-n.png",
};
export default function App() {
  return {
    /** Render app content**/
  };
}
```

Later in your `Card` component

```js
import { StaticAssets } from "../App.js";

const CardList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((listing) => {
        setData(listing);
      });
  }, []);

  const compileImagePath = (imageName) => {
   // Use static embedded image reference to access  image data
    return StaticAssets[imageName];
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        const imagePath = compileImagePath(item.image);

        return <Image source={imagePath} style={styles.image} />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CardList;

``
```